# Erro ao retornar StringStr

Tags: php, string

Tenho a seguinte função em php ele me retorna uma string da pagina para que eu possa fazer if e else com a informação retornada, porem ocorre um erro: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in /storage/ssd3/854/1950854/public_html/config.php on line 22

como posso resolver isso ? (aparentemente a linha com o erro é a name porem não sei como resolver)

```html
function GetStr($string, $start, $end){

$str = explode($start, $string);
$str = explode($end, $str[1]);
return $str[0];
}

name = "sair";
$valor = GetStr($resultado, 'name='",");

echo $valor;
```

Comment: Altere para `$name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neste caso é um erro de sintaxe, a sua variável `name` está sem o cifão `$`, que é obrigatório para as variáveis conforme definição da linguagem PHP. Portanto incluindo o cifão deve funcionar:

```
function GetStr($string, $start, $end){

$str = explode($start, $string);
$str = explode($end, $str[1]);
return $str[0];
}

$name = "sair";
$valor = GetStr($resultado, 'name='",");

echo $valor;
```